# staring service in windows through nsis

Tags: python, windows-services, celery, nsis

i have compiled myscripts to myscripts.exe file using pyinstaller --onefile
myscripts.py contain

```
import os
os.popen("python celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -P solo -c 1")
```

Once i got .exe file

```
  SimpleSC::InstallService "ERP" "ERP Data Cloud" "16" "2" "$INSTDIR\myscript1.exe" "" "" ""
  SimpleSC::StartService "ERP" "" 30
```

i compiled using nsis got my setup.exe

Now when i see the service window i can see the service is added bt the status is blank, even i try to start the service manually i got an error
`control request is not timely fashion`

after install

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\dist\myscripts.exe"
```

i am able to run myscripts.exe which start celery with no problem, But i want it to run in service .

now Question
Am i doing it completly worng way, Or i need to add something,
What am i missing.

Answer (score 0):

A service has to call [specific service functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you are unable to write a proper service you could try a helper utility like [Srvany](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service)...